# What is the equivalent of 'Microsoft.Web.Services3' in .Net 4.5

Tags: vb.net, web-services, soap, wsdl

The status of SOAPsupport in .net 4.5 is very ambiguous for me...

I'd like to do RPC on my home router (It is based on OpenRG)

I am trying to write a soap client and I'm baffled by all the tutorials that say to import that assembly.

I have no WSDL file for the CWMP proprietary version of the maker, so I'm on my bare foots (reversing from the Web UI).

Optionally, is  there any program to easily create/modify WSDL files with a fancy UI and everything else? Maybe my best option is to start with some WSDL file for generic CWMP and modify it with the extensions of the maker?

Comment: WCF replaced WSE back in .NET 3.0. Never use WSE.

Comment: Never used, indeed. I'd really like some (even basic) example for SOAP...

Comment: See [tag:wcf] and [How to Consume a Web Service](http://johnwsaunders3.wordpress.com/2009/05/17/how-to-consume-a-web-service/)

Comment: The service in question is poorly (really) documented so the servicereference fails. Is there any way to do this manually?

Comment: See [svcutil.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa347733.aspx)

Comment: @JohnSaunders 501 Not Implemented